# TRANSFORMERS: Asking to pad but the tokenizer does not have a padding token

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tokenize, huggingface-transformers

In trying to evaluate several transformers models sequentially with the same dataset to check which one performs better.

The list of models is this one:

```
MODELS = [
      ('xlm-mlm-enfr-1024'   ,"XLMModel"),
      ('distilbert-base-cased', "DistilBertModel"),
      ('bert-base-uncased'     ,"BertModel"),
      ('roberta-base'        ,"RobertaModel"),
      ("cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment","RobertaSentTW"),
      ('xlnet-base-cased'     ,"XLNetModel"),
      #('ctrl'                ,"CTRLModel"),
      ('transfo-xl-wt103'    ,"TransfoXLModel"),
      ('bert-base-cased'       ,"BertModelUncased"),
      ('xlm-roberta-base'     ,"XLMRobertaModel"),
      ('openai-gpt'           ,"OpenAIGPTModel"),
      ('gpt2'                 ,"GPT2Model")
```

All of them work fine until the `'ctrl'` model, which returns this error:

`Asking to pad, but the tokenizer does not have a padding token. Please select a token to use as 'pad_token' '(tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token e.g.)' or add a new pad token via 'tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})'.`

When tokenizing the sentences of my dataset.

The tokenizing code is

```
SEQ_LEN = MAX_LEN #(50)

for pretrained_weights, model_name in MODELS:

print("***************** INICIANDO " ,model_name,", weights ",pretrained_weights, "********* ")
print("carganzo el tokenizador ()")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_weights)
print("creando el modelo preentrenado")
transformer_model = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_weights)
print("aplicando el tokenizador al dataset")

##APLICAMOS EL TOKENIZADOR##

def tokenize(sentence):
  
  tokens = tokenizer.encode_plus(sentence, max_length=MAX_LEN,
                               truncation=True, padding='max_length',
                               add_special_tokens=True, return_attention_mask=True,
                               return_token_type_ids=False, return_tensors='tf')
  return tokens['input_ids'], tokens['attention_mask']

# initialize two arrays for input tensors
Xids = np.zeros((len(df), SEQ_LEN))
Xmask = np.zeros((len(df), SEQ_LEN))

for i, sentence in enumerate(df['tweet']):
    Xids[i, :], Xmask[i, :] = tokenize(sentence)
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        print(i)  # do this so we can see some progress


arr = df['label'].values  # take label column in df as array

labels = np.zeros((arr.size, arr.max()+1))  # initialize empty (all zero) label array
labels[np.arange(arr.size), arr] = 1  # add ones in indices where we have a value`
```

I have tried to define the padding tokens as the solution tells me, but then this error appears

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (50,)
```

in line

```
Xids[i, :], Xmask[i, :] = tokenize(sentence)
```

I have also tried [this solution](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/8452), and it doesn't work either.

If you have managed to read until here, thank you.

Any help is needed.

Comment: `could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (50,)` says that the shape of tensors returned from `tokenize` was `3` while `Xids` has space reserved for tensors of shape `50`. The shape mismatches. When you do `return tokens['input_ids'], tokens['attention_mask']`, make sure both tensors are of shape `SEQ_LEN`, if not `pad them with zeros` or clip them. Find out a way to do so in tensorflow as you are using tensorflow `return_tensors='tf'`. I know only pytorch

Answer (score 19):

[kkgarg idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70550408/11664121) was right, but you also need to update your model token embeding size.
So, the code will be:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_weights)
model = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_weights)
if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
    tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
    model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69194717/11664121) related issue.

Comment: Would there be a potential downside to including the last line of code (model.resize_...) in the if-branch? This line of code will only be needed when the PAD token was added, so the embeddings only need to be resized in this case?

Comment: this doesn't actually work anymore, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633368/why-does-the-falcon-qlora-tutorial-code-use-eos-token-as-pad-token/76639568#76639568

Answer (score 10):

You can add the `[PAD]` token using `add_special_tokens` API.

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_weights)
if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
    tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
```

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Comment: This correctly added the padding token to the tokenizer, but afterwards I got another error because my embeddings did not expect this new token. I found [this issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3021) that mimics the padding behavior using the attention mask.

Comment: you still need to add this to the embedding table if the model doesn't have a pad token.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to assigning the `eos_token` (end-of-sentence token) to the `pad_token`.

```py
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
```